# Python: setting max for bank withdraw

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I am still trying to get the hang of it. I'm attempting to change the processing function in the following code so that the user can not withdraw more money then what the "bank" has on record, which is 500. I was hoping that someone could help. Would I enter an if statement for >500?

```
#Simple Bank Atm
def main():
    PIN=7777;balance=500;pin=0;success=False
    Pin=getInput(pin)
    Pin,PIN,balance,success=processing(pin,PIN,balance,success)
    Display(success,balance)

#Input Function
def getInput(pin):
    pin=int(input(“Please enter your PIN:”))
    return pin

#Processing Function
def processing(pin,PIN,balance,success):
    if pin==PIN:
        success=True
        amt=float(input(“How much would you like to withdraw?”))
        balance=balance-amt
        return pin,PIN,balance,success
    else:
        success=false
        return pin,PIN,balance,success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `if` condition to do this.

```
if amt <= balance: #Can't withdraw over your current balance
    balance -= amt
else:
    print("Error. Amount exceeds funds on record.")
```

Also, other things aside you're returning the same thing inside your `if` and `else` condition and if this is what you really want to return it's redundant to have it in both. You can just have it after your else statement at the same indentation level

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    PIN=7777;balance=500;pin=0;success=False
    Pin=getInput(pin)
    Pin,PIN,balance,success=processing(pin,PIN,balance,success)
    Display(success,balance)

#Input Function
def getInput(pin):
    pin=int(input("Please enter your PIN:"))
    return pin

#Processing Function
def processing(pin,PIN,balance,success):
    if pin==PIN:
        success=True
        amt=float(input("How much would you like to withdraw?"))
        if balance<amt:
            print("Amount to draw is greater than balance.")
            return pin,PIN,balance,false
        balance=balance-amt
        return pin,PIN,balance,success
    else:
        success=false
        return pin,PIN,balance,success
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should use an if statement - this should happen before they can withdrawal the amount (balance = balance - amt).

So you could do something like this:

```
if amt <= balance:
    balance -= amt
    return True
else:
    # do not change balance and stop withdrawal
    return False
```